# Imprimir varias listas cada uma em uma coluna

Tags: python-3.x

Eu tenho cinco listas que foram extraídas de uma tabela do Excel em CSV. Gostaria de saber como eu faço para imprimir elas no terminal uma do lado da outra, acredito que possa ser feito com um laço `for`, mas não me acertei com a sintaxe.

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
d = []
e = []

dataset = open ("Teste_Plotagem.csv","r")

for line in dataset:
    line = line.strip()
    A,B,C,D,E = line.split(";")
    a.append(A)
    b.append(B)
    c.append(C)
    d.append(D)
    e.append(E)

dataset.close()

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(d)
print(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = ["Pedro", "Ricardo", "Renato", "Sonia", "Rosana"]
b = ["Analista", "Financeiro", "Controlador", "Produção", "Logística"]
c = [4000, 3100, 5000, 1900, 1400]

x = 0
for i in a:
    print("{}\t\t\t{}\t\t\t{}".format(a[x], b[x], c[x]))
    x+=1
```

Output:

```
Pedro           Analista            4000
Ricardo         Financeiro          3100
Renato          Controlador         5000
Sonia           Producaoo           1900
Rosana          Logistica           1400
```

Que tal? Você pode também criar uma unica lista:

```
a = ["Pedro", "Ricardo", "Renato", "Sonia", "Rosana"]
b = ["Analista", "Financeiro", "Controlador", "Produção", "Logística"]
c = [4000, 3100, 5000, 1900, 1400]

lst = []

x = 0
for i in a:
    temp_lst = [a[x], b[x], c[x]]
    lst.append(temp_lst)
    x+=1

for line in lst:
    print(line)
```

Output:

```
['Pedro', 'Analista', 4000]
['Ricardo', 'Financeiro', 3100]
['Renato', 'Controlador', 5000]
['Sonia', 'Produção', 1900]
['Rosana', 'Logística', 1400]
```